# Point a Go-Ethereum contract instance at a different address

Tags: go-ethereum, golang, abigen

I am running a golang backend that will interact with tens of thousands of deployed contracts that are all the same, just with different addresses (uniswap pools). I am thinking that it would be more efficient to create a single instance and pass in the appropriate address when I need to interact with that contract instead of having tens of thousands of instances in memory. Is this possible in golang with the ABIgen tool? I would prefer not to do anything hacky, but I haven't found a good way to go about this.